# Can I install SSIS designer without having an instance of SQL Server installed on my local machine?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

All I want is SSIS designer, but the best option I see is "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008".  Is it possible to just install the designer if I don't have an instance installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008" option is the right path to install what you need.  A few steps into the installation, you'll get a Feature Selection screen.  You can select the tools you need.  And, you don't have to install the server components.